# Initialize a largest product counter as an "infinitely" small number

Tags: java, initialization, int

I'm implementing a simple algorithm in java that takes in an array of integers, and finds and returns the largest product of adjacent integers in the array. **To do this I first initialized a variable called largestProduct which I use to keep track of the current biggest (best) product found. I want to make sure that the initial value of this product is immediately replaced by the first product I find, so I set the initial value to a very small number (-1000000)**. This solution works since each number in the array is restricted to the domain -1,000 - 1,000 so the smallest the product could be is 1,000,00. However, this solution seems nonideal, and would need to be changed if the domain changed.

To try and guarantee that my initial value be replaced I tried setting largestProduct's initial value to null, and also tried not giving it any intial value, but these both gave me a compilation error. **So my question is, is there a way to set a variable's (of type int) initial value to an "infinitely" small value, or what would be the best way to handle this situation otherwise?**

Here is my code

```
int adjacentElementsProduct(int[] inputArray) {
int largestProduct = -1000000; 
int n = 1;
while(n < inputArray.length){
    int tempProduct = inputArray[n-1]*inputArray[n];
    if(tempProduct > largestProduct){
        largestProduct = tempProduct;
    }
    n++;
}
return largestProduct;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the array is of length at least 2, the approach I would take would be to calculate the first product (`[1]`*`[0]`), and then start iterating at `n=2`.

Answer (score 2):

`Integer.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest value that can possibly be stored in an `int`, namely -2<sup>31</sup>.